# Acumatica Implementation and data entry

Tags: acumatica, implementation, data-entry

Am supposed to do Acumatica implementation for a client but the client has requested that all the transactions from the start of their financial year, July, be added into the system. Is there a way to import the transactions in bulk instead of adding one transactions, SO/PR/IN, at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an import scenario to bulk upload records. YOu could also optionally use the Contract-Based API to programmatically push transactions through. This help article might also help. https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6ef1dca7-4ca7-47b4-9adc-b67de5231d4f

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you take a look at the online training(Acumatica's Open University). Import Scenarios are the tool you are most likely looking for.

https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/reporting/i100-integration-scenarios/

The above covers how to setup bulk imports for a variety of scenarios. If you are struggling with a specific import scenario the community forums are a great place to get help with that.